# Subsetting for matrices

Tags: r, matrix

I'm playing around with some data, my matrix looks as shown in results:

```
results
      [,1]   [,2]      [,3]
 [1,]  1.7 0.0015 -1566.276
 [2,]  1.7 0.0016 -1564.695
 [3,]  1.7 0.0017 -1564.445
 [4,]  1.7 0.0018 -1565.373
 [5,]  1.7 0.0019 -1567.352
 [6,]  1.7 0.0020 -1570.274
 [7,]  1.8 0.0015 -1568.299
 [8,]  1.8 0.0016 -1565.428
 [9,]  1.8 0.0017 -1563.965
[10,]  1.8 0.0018 -1563.750
[11,]  1.8 0.0019 -1564.647
[12,]  1.8 0.0020 -1566.544
[13,]  1.9 0.0015 -1571.798
[14,]  1.9 0.0016 -1567.635
[15,]  1.9 0.0017 -1564.960
[16,]  1.9 0.0018 -1563.602
[17,]  1.9 0.0019 -1563.418
[18,]  1.9 0.0020 -1564.289
[19,]  2.0 0.0015 -1576.673
[20,]  2.0 0.0016 -1571.220
[21,]  2.0 0.0017 -1567.332
[22,]  2.0 0.0018 -1564.831
[23,]  2.0 0.0019 -1563.566
[24,]  2.0 0.0020 -1563.410
```

I wanted to print the row where the maximum on the 3rd column occurs, so I split it down in the following 2 lines:

```
max(results[,3])
results[results[,3] == -1563.41,]
```

The result didn't give me the desired row.
I tried putting the value in inverted commas as so:

```
max(results[,3])
results[results[,3] == "-1563.41",]
```

but this didn't work either.

the only code which worked was when I nested the max line of code in the 2nd line of code as so:

```
results[results[,3] == max(results[,3]),]
```

could someone please explain why breaking it down into steps didn't work??

I tried turning it into a data frame which didn't work either. using the filter from the tidyverse package didn't work either.

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

R prints numbers to a maximum of `getOption("digits")` significant digits. I suspect that `-1563.410` is the maximum rounded to seven significant digits, *not* the exact maximum. If no element of `results[, 3]` is exactly equal to the rounded number `-1563.410`, then

```r
results[results[, 3] == -1563.41, ]
```

returns a 0-by-3 matrix. Meanwhile, `max(results[, 3])` is the exact maximum, so

```r
results[results[, 3] == max(results[, 3]), ]
```

returns the matrix subset that you want.

Note that if there are `n` rows whose third element is equal to `max(results[, 3])`, then the subset is a length-3 vector if `n = 1` and an `n`-by-3 matrix if `n > 1` (see `?Extract`). If, in the `n > 1` case, you only want the first of the `n` rows, then you should do:

```r
results[which.max(results[, 3]), ]
```

Comment: understood, so basically it's because I'm asking it to find a rounded up number which is not an exact solution. thanks so much for your help